$\forall\alpha\in(0,1),|x+y|^\alpha\leq|x|^\alpha+|y|^\alpha$
In proving a certain question, I ran into the following problem:
$$|x+y|^\alpha \leqslant |x|^\alpha + |y|^\alpha,\quad\forall\alpha\in(0,1)$$
My attempt as followings:
First, the function $f(x)=|x|^\alpha$ is a concave funtion when $x>0$, so for $\forall u,v,t\in(0,1)$, we have
$$f(tu+(1-t)v)\geqslant tf(u)+(1-t)f(v)$$
i.e.
$$|tu+(1-t)v|^\alpha \geqslant t|u|^\alpha + (1-t)|v|^\alpha$$
then we let $u=x,v=x+y$, then we have
$$|y|^\alpha\geqslant t|x|^\alpha + (1-t)|x+y|^\alpha$$
i.e.
$$(1-t)|x+y|^\alpha \leqslant t|x|^\alpha + |y|^\alpha$$
Let $t=0$, we have:
$$|x+y|^\alpha\leqslant |y|^\alpha\leqslant |y|^\alpha + |x|^\alpha$$

How would you prove that it is concave?

@HyperbolicPDEfriend The second derivative is negative.

The value of $\pm y$ on the left-hand side of the third equation from the bottom only occurs for certain values of $t$, i.e. we need to solve $tx+(1-t)(x+y)=\pm y$ for $t$. That yields $x+(1-t)y=\pm y$, i.e. either $t=\dfrac{y}{x}$ or $t=\dfrac{y}{x}+2$, neither of which is guaranteed to be in $(0,1)$.

@AlexanderBurstein But it does not admit a derivative in $0$. By that logic, $x \mapsto - \lvert x \rvert$ would be convex

@HyperbolicPDEfriend The question says "when $x>0$", and then $|x|=x$.

Sorry, my mistake @AlexanderBurstein

This is correct. As pointed out in the comments, based on the context, it might be warranted to justify concavity.
Let me offer another proof. Fix $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $\alpha\in (0,1)$. If $|x|^\alpha+|y|^\alpha=0$, then $x=y=0$ and $$|x+y|^\alpha=0=|x|^\alpha+|y|^\alpha.$$  Note that $$|cx+cy|^\alpha=|c|^\alpha |x+y|^\alpha$$ and $$|cx|^\alpha+|cy|^\alpha=|c|^\alpha (|x|^\alpha+|y|^\alpha)$$ for any real number $c$, so it suffices to prove the inequality in the case that $|x|^\alpha+|y|^\alpha=1$. But this means $|x|,|y|\leqslant 1$, and $|x|^\alpha\geqslant |x|$ and $|y|^\alpha \geqslant |y|$, since $\alpha\in (0,1)$. Then $$|x+y|^\alpha \leqslant ||x|+|y||^\alpha \leqslant ||x|^\alpha+|y|^\alpha|^\alpha=1=|x|^\alpha+|y|^\alpha.$$

A smart way of Normalization!

This can be proved by one-liner for non-trivial $x,y$ and $\forall\alpha\in(0,1)$.
$$
1=\frac{x}{x+y}+\frac{y}{x+y}\le\left|\frac{x}{x+y}\right|^\alpha+\left|\frac{y}{x+y}\right|^\alpha=\frac{|x|^\alpha+|y|^\alpha}{ |x+y|^\alpha}.
$$
EDIT for extension:
This can be generalized for $p+q=1$ and $\alpha>0$ to $$|px+qy|^\alpha\leq p|x|^\alpha+q|y|^\alpha$$
Actually, the map $x\mapsto x^\alpha$ for $x\geq 0$ and $\alpha>1$ is convex, since its second derivative is $r(r-1)x^{r-2}\geq 0$.
We have
\begin{align}
\left|{px+qy}\right|^\alpha\leq \left({p|x|+q|y|}\right)^\alpha\leq {p|x|^\alpha+q|y|^\alpha},\quad\text{ if } \alpha>1.
\end{align}

Yes, your proof covering the convexity and concavity of the function suffices. Here, I'll provide another proof for you, hoping it helps.
Let's assume $|x| \leq |y|$ and $\alpha = \frac{1}{p}$, $p \in (1, \infty)$.

When $|x| = 0$, the conclusion is obvious.
When $|x|\ne 0$, divide both sides by $|y|$ to obtain an equivalent inequality:
$$\sqrt[p]{\left|1 + \frac{x}{y}\right|} \leq 1 + \sqrt[p]{\left|\frac{x}{y}\right|},$$
where $0 < \left|\frac{x}{y}\right| \leq 1$.
If $\frac{x}{y} < 0$, then $\left|1 + \frac{x}{y}\right| < 1$.
$$\sqrt[p]{\left|1 + \frac{x}{y}\right|} < 1 < 1 + \sqrt[p]{\left|\frac{x}{y}\right|},$$
which holds true.
If $\frac{x}{y} > 0$, then $\left|\frac{x}{y}\right| = \frac{x}{y}$. Let $t = \sqrt[p]{\frac{x}{y}} \leq 1$, then the original inequality becomes:
$$\sqrt[p]{1 + t^{p}} \leq 1 + t \Leftrightarrow 1 + t^{p} \leq (1 + t)^{p}.$$
Moreover, since $t \leq 1$ and $p \geq 1$,
$$1 + t^p \leq 1 + t \leq (1 + t)^p.$$
Thus, the proof is complete.

